# Sql Server Javascript date format varchar to date

Tags: javascript, sql-server, date, datetime, date-conversion

on SQL Server 2012 a have Varchar(200) containing values like (JS .toString() date):

```
Thu Jul 05 2018 20:43:14 GMT+0200
```

is there an easy way to convert the varchar to datetime?
I tried with the

```
convert
```

command but I couldn't find any date style.

Comment: You can parse the string yourself (maybe 4 lines of code) or use one of the many libraries that include a parser (e.g. [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha), [*moment.js*](http://momentjs.com)).

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the JavaScript use `toISOString` instead of `toString`.
Then on Sql Server:

```
convert(datetime, @YourVarChar, 127)
```

If you can't then try this:

```
DECLARE @myDate as varchar(35) = 'Thu Jul 05 2018 20:43:14 GMT+0200';
Declare @myMonth as char(3),
@myDay as char(2),
@myYear as char(4),
@myTime as char(8),
@parseMe as varchar(24),
@newDateTime as datetime;

set @myMonth = SUBSTRING(@myDate,5,3);
set @myDay = SUBSTRING(@myDate,9,2);
set @myYear = SUBSTRING(@myDate,12,4);
set @myTime = SUBSTRING(@myDate,17,8);
set @parseMe = @myDay + ' ' + @myMonth + ' ' + @myYear + ' ' + @myTime + ':000'
set @newDateTime = convert(datetime,@parseMe,113)
```

A little dirty, but works. Also doesn't take timezone into consideration.

Comment: @NkSP Added t-sql to my answer.